# VBA: Adding an identifier to values in column if there are duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a identifier to the back of the string if there are duplicate values.

I considered a for loop with a counter but it simply gave me a sequence of numbers in each cells.

Is there another way I can approach this matter?

```
Sub Macro1()
For i = 1 To 10
    For N = 1 To 10
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & N) Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) & counter
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next N
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,A2)>1,A2 & "_" & COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),A2)`

Comment: Thanks Tim! Is there a way I can implement this to an array?

Answer (score 1):

There might be other solutions, but this is what I actually came up with.
Don't forget to add this reference to your project:
**Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime -> tick checkbox**

```
Sub Macro1()
' Add reference to project:
' Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime -> tick checkbox
Dim dDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rngInput As Range
Dim sOutputCol As String
Dim lRow As Long, lCount As Long

    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET_NAME")  ' SHEET_NAME: the name of the sheet where input is
        Set rngInput = .Range("A1:A10")         ' A1:A10: the range on the sheet where input is
        sOutputCol = "C"                        ' sOutputCol: output column's letter
        
        For lRow = rngInput.Rows(1).Row To rngInput.Rows(rngInput.Rows.Count).Row
            If dDict.Exists(rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2) Then
                lCount = dDict(rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2)
                dDict.Remove rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2
                dDict.Add rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2, lCount + 1
            Else
                dDict.Add rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2, 1
            End If
            .Cells(lRow, sOutputCol).Value2 = rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2 & "_" & dDict(rngInput.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2)
        Next lRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! Is there an alternative to using a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary is a fast tool, you should consider using it! Especially if your input range has large amount of unique values. Is there anything that prevents you from using it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different Dictionary approach, which gives you an array of the final values.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim arr, r As Long, dict As Object, rng As Range, v, tmp
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B20")
    arr = rng.Value                 'get the input values in an array
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)     'loop over all the values
        v = arr(r, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(v) Then  'new value?
            dict.Add v, Array(r, 1) 'store row for the first occurence and start the count
        Else
            tmp = dict(v)       'not new value: pull array from dict
            tmp(1) = tmp(1) + 1 'increment count for this value
            If tmp(1) = 2 Then arr(tmp(0), 1) = arr(tmp(0), 1) & "_1" 'second instance? Flag the first occurence also...
            arr(r, 1) = arr(r, 1) & "_" & tmp(1)   'flag the n'th instance
            dict(v) = tmp                          're-store the array
        End If
    Next r
    
    rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = arr 'output the (updated) array
End Sub
```